# Closed form distribution of a special function of random variables

Tags: probability

Let $P$ be a random variable that can take on values in $[0,1]$, and let $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ be random variables whose domain is unimportant. Call $a = A-B$, $c = C-D$, and $\rho = \dfrac{c}{a+c}$. I'm interested in the random variable

$$Y=\begin{cases} 
(1-P)c & P > \rho\\
Pa  & P < \rho
\end{cases}$$

I'm trying to understand its properties. Its expectation, variance, and maybe even a closed-form solution for its PDF in special cases. My motivation is that I have reduced a toy operations research problem to the formula in Y, where P is the probability of an event happening. A, B, C, and D are unknown values. The quantity Y is a simplified formula of the quantity the decision maker would like to optimize.

I thought maybe the easiest possible case would be where all the random variables $P$ $A$ $B$ $C$ and $D$ were also uniform on $[0,1]$, but when I look at that I get

$$Pr(Y<y) = Pr \left( 
\begin{cases} 
(1-P)c & P > \rho\\
Pa  & P < \rho 
\end{cases} 
 < y \right)$$

So I have no idea how to proceed to find an analytic solution from here, with the two cases and so many different random variables on the left-hand side in the probability. The big issue is that $\rho$ is a function of the other rvs. Maybe a closed-form solution for PDF is going to be too hard, but perhaps with some strategic choices on $P$ $A$ $B$ $C$ and $D$ there is a way to maybe solve for an expectation?

I feel like there is an interesting structure to this random variable $Y$ worth studying. The $P$ and $1-P$ showing up in the two cases makes the RV possibly have some nice symmetries. When I simulate this rv it has a beautifully simple looking histogram

[image: Histogram drawing P, A, B, C, D uniform]